# Block requests starting by string

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I would like to block all requests starting with `/search?q=` as they generate unwanted load on my server.

Following this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640807/how-to-block-bot-requests-to-urls-that-match-a-common-pattern-in-apache , I tried the following code:

```
<Location />
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search?q=[^/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
</Location>
```

but it's blocking way too many URLs (like everything starting with search)

I tried different variations but they didn't work. What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it's blocking way too many urls (like everything starting with search)

The code you posted won't do that? In fact, the code you posted is unlikely to block anything, unless there was a URL encoded `?` (ie. `%3F`) in the original request URL?

However, in order to match the query string (ie. `q=`) then you need to match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. The `REQUEST_URI` Apache server variable contains the URL-path only (no query string).

So, in order to block all requests that start `/search?q=` then you would need something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=
RewriteRule ^/?search$ - [F]
```

This ensures that the URL-path matches `/search` and the query string starts `q=`.

The `NC` flag is not required unless you need to also match `Q=` in the query string.

The `L` flag is not required with the `F` flag as it is implied.

> **UDPATE:** I put these directives directly in the server config, because I have many virtual hosts (websites) on this server and I would like this rule to apply to all.

That's probably your problem. The mod_rewrite directives in the server config are overridden by the virtual host by default and effectively ignored. The vHosts won't inherit the mod_rewrite directives from the server config unless you specifically enable mod_rewrite inheritance, which you would ordinarily do from the vhost container. However, on Apache 2.4.8+ you can do this in the main server config (*server* context). For example:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

`InheritDownBefore` ensures that the directives in the server config are executed *before* the directives in the vhost.

Comment: Should I put the code you gave me between `<Location />
RewriteEngine On
...
</Location>` like I did? At the moment your code is giving me a 404 "The requested URL  was not found on this server." for /search?q=, but also /search?, /searc and any url that does not exist

Comment: Where exactly have you put this code? Main server config? Virtual host? `<Directory>` section? Have you restarted Apache? The `<Location />` wrapper is probably not required. You need the `RewriteEngine On` directive. If you are seeing a 404 when requesting `/search?q=<anything>` then this code is not being processed. What other directives do you have?

Comment: I've put this in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. I also have `<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>` above in that file is that the problem? Yes I'm seeing a 404 but only when I add that code.

Comment: That `<Directory />` container is OK. So, you are putting these directives directly in the server coinfig? You don't have a `<VirtualHost>` container for your site? Just stepping back for a moment... ignoring this code, how would `/search?q=` normally get processed by your server?

Comment: Yes I put these directives directly in the server config, because I have many virtual hosts (websites) on this server and I would like this rule to apply to all. But I also have config files for each virtual host. I don't know what you mean by how would the url get processed by my server.

Comment: The virtual hosts won't inherit the mod_rewrite directives by default - they will be ignored. I've updated my answer. What normally happens when `/search?q=` is requested? Does it return a 404 after being processed by a front-controller? Or simply 404s? I'm wondering how this is putting excessive load on your server? Implementing this directive may not help much anyway as the request is still reaching your server.

Comment: that was it! it works now. normally when /search?q= is requested wordpress returns a "page not found" with a search form. So the whole wordpress site is still loaded. I've been told it will be much more efficient this way even though the request is still reaching the server.

Comment: Ah yes, this will certainly prevent the request from being processed by WordPress (and prevent that unnecessary overhead).